# Enterprise-level MCQ engine for Test Center

Tags: intranet, assessment

I am looking for locally installable software which is designed for test center institutes and offers the following:

1. Entering the system requires credentials.
2. Multi-level users, e.g. administrators, instructors, testers, etc.
3. Instructors can insert new questions in a question bank.
4. Testers can perform the exam, and at the end, the answers will be sent to a central database which is connected within the network.
5. The system can generate reports regarding the examiners, how they performed, their weakness area, ..etc.
6. The administrators can modify the policies of the exams, and can create exams and add questions from question banks.

**Note**: I prefer a software to install in local network, for security concerns.

Comment: Finally I've found one ([Adit Testdesk](http://www.aditsoftware.com/products.php)). I am looking for more.

Answer (score 0):

QST Quiz/Survey/Test Online - qstonline.ca fulfills your requirements. Open source, install locally, question bank, ssl, multiple levels of users, scalable, too many features to list.

Comment: QST Quiz/Survey/Test Online is a nightmare you have to go through 15 pages of installation instructions